# How I do connect oracle database with PyQt ? What's the procedure?

Tags: python, database, oracle, pyqt

I want to connect my project with PyQt. I searched a lot off in internet . But it's matter of sorrow that i don't any understandable or effective method or procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link, in which the author explains how to use `cx_Oracle` in Python.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3WVqn3WySs

After fetching your data from your Oracle DB, you can update your PyQt widgets based on the data.